# How can i completely uninstall Skyrim files?

Tags: wine, uninstall, games

I installed Skyrim and attempted to play it with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, however there were audio problems. After using uninstall.exe to remove Skyrim (I had wine installed), I now see the following in my application menu: [The Skyrim main game and the uninstallation.exe is still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igBJb.png)

Even if I removed wine from Snap, it is still displaying to me. What ought I to do?

Answer (score 0):

Enter `wine explorer` in terminal and try to uninstall Skyrim from there